# How to write a .log file about commits

Tags: git, bash, shell, ubuntu, assembla

I'm just starting to use git, and hosting the repository in assembla. I would like to keep track of the commits I make in a .log file. Can anybody point me in the right direction for doing this? I've been googling for a while but haven't found anything that can get me started.

Thanks!

Comment: What about git log ? Isn't that enough?

Comment: Yes! thanks, I used that and redirected the output to a file git log > project.log

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150690/maintaining-a-changelog-txt-file-in-a-dvcs. I'm quite sure that you don't want to hold **every** commit in your changelog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use git log and redirect that to a file.

Answer (score 0):

git log --pretty=format:'%h : %s' --graph > commit_log.log

This would give you summary with the graph of commits.